# Spring Security invalidating http sessions on multiple applications?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, tomcat9

I have two separate Java web applications running on my local machine on separate Tomcat 9 instances via my IntelliJ IDE.  One is on port 8080, the other is on port 8081.  Both use Spring (5.1.4) + Spring Security (3.2.5) and I re-used a lot of the code between the two applications for getting them up and running.

The issue I'm facing is that if I log into Application A successfully (:8080), then launch a new browser tab to Application B (:8081) and fail a login attempt, if I refresh Application A tab, that's also now logged out.

What configuration parameter would need to be unique between the two applications to make sure they don't intercept with one another?  Similarly I'd want to be able to log into both simultaneously in the same browser session without interference...

Here's my web security config -- both are pretty much identical EXCEPT for the rememberMe key value:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/secure/**")
             .access("hasRole('MEMBER')")
         .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/Login")
             .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/Master")
             .usernameParameter("username")
             .passwordParameter("password")
             .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
             .permitAll()
         .and()
             .logout()
             .invalidateHttpSession(true)
             .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
             .logoutSuccessUrl("/Login?logout=true")
         .and()
             .csrf()
         .and()
             .rememberMe()
             .key("UNIQUE_KEY_APP_XYZ")
         .and()
             .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
             .exceptionHandling()
             .accessDeniedPage("/Login?expired=true")
         .and()
             .sessionManagement()
             .maximumSessions(5)
             .expiredUrl("/Login?expired=true");


    if (this.enableHttps) {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

My web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml classes are both pretty plain but can include those if necessary.  Nothing really stands out to me from the IntelliJ Tomcat server launch parameters either.

One thing worth noting is that they do use the same Tomcat application directory / home...

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT: New Revelation:**

If I launch Application A with the default Application context ("/") and Application B with a separate context ("/SecondApp"), the above issue doesn't happen at all.  That is, I can access App A at localhost:8080/ and App B at localhost:8081/SecondApp and now I don't have this glitchy session issue.  I guess updated question would be, how can I launch them both at localhost:808X/ without the above session behavioral issue?

I guess this is more a Tomcat issue than Spring-related issue now?

Comment: `I re-used a lot of the code between the two applications for getting them up and running.` Will you explain how you reused? Is one app communicating with other app? for any(like  API access?)

Comment: Also explain cases. **Case1:** user1 do login for  app1 and user2 do login for app2. in this case any thing going wrong? **Case2:** If user logs out in one app then for user in another app working correctly? from your explaination it is invalidating session when 401(Unauthorized exception) occurs in another app right?

Comment: Oh no, sorry.  I just meant in terms of configuration files (e.g. that entire block of configuration code, and identical web.xml + dispatcher-servlet.xml files).  These two web apps run entirely independent of each other and do not communicate with one another in any way (aside from this security/authentication glitch I'm facing apparently).

Comment: check for logs getting printed in the app where it is invalidated. Set log level to TRACE

Comment: **Case 1:** If user1 is logged into app1 and user2 logs into app2, user1 automatically gets logged out of app1 when I refresh tab (kicks back to login screen).  **Case 2::** I can't seem to have both logged in concurrently after testing Case 1 so I'm not 100% sure.  If I log into app1 then log into app2, then hit the app1 log-out button, I receive a "HTTP Status 405 ? Method Not Allowed" error -- but presumably because it's calling logout even though session was already invalidated?  I'm not sure...

Comment: Also there is a listener `HttpSessionListener` implement that listener and register to servlet context. It has methods on create and on destroy. There you can just put a debug message so that it will prints out when session is destroyed.

Comment: By chance anywhere if you have hardcoded URL, As you have CSRF enabled. Cross site request may cause invalidating session. While you make login to 2nd application observe logs in 1st application. Make sure it not prints any logs.

Comment: hardcoded URL means application running in 8080 should not send request to application running in 8081. It may be resource like js/css/imgs

Comment: I created a `HttpSessionListener` on app1.  When I load the page, I see a session created.  When I log-in, no logging occurs.  When I log out, I see session destroyed then a new session created.
Now when I log into app 1, then log into app 2, then refresh app 1, I just see a new session created.  No session destroyed call on app 1is ever made.
I've confirmed that there are no port hardcodings anywhere in the code, and have launched app 1 on a different port as well with the same results.

Comment: Your login. jsp page should have `@page session=false` something like this. In jsp page if you not mention this header it will create session. Do you remember about implicit objects in jsp? Avoid that session creation. But it is not related to your problem. By removing that it will help to analyse debug logs

Comment: `<%@ page session="false" %>` add this in first line of login.jsp

Comment: Even with `<%@ page session="false" %>` I still see the `sessionCreated(...)` method being hit on the `HttpSessionListener`.